# Best practice for keys and classes with Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

Having a hard time using a NoSQL database for the first time.
My problem now is that many times I find it harder to code without the key as an attribute in my POJOs. What's your approach for that?

My POJO:

```
public class Trip {
    @Exclude
    private String id;
    private String cityId;
    private String tripName;
    private long arrivalDate;
    private int duration;
}
```

My data structure:

```
-KIqtlY8VQFCuYmi-fWc
 arrivalDate: 2310943
 cityId: "paris"
 duration: 4
 tripName: "Paris in June"
```

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think there's any one best-practice for this, so I'm going to vote to close as a primarily opinion based question. My personal preference is to pass snapshots around in cases where I need both key and value. I must admit that I sometimes wish that Firebase had a type-safe, generic variant of `DataSnapshot`, i.e. `DataSnapshot<Trip>`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your preference @FrankvanPuffelen I'd never consider that. Would love to see alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to create a Key/Object pair and use that Pair instead of just the object.

```
List<Pair<String, Trip>> mTripPairs = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String key = dsp.getKey();
    Trip trip = dsp.getValue(Trip.class);
    mTripPairs.add(new Pair<>(key, trip));
}
```

Then you may access the key and your object any time.

```
String key = mTripPairs.get(0).first;
Trip trip = mTripPairs.get(0).second;
```